# I am struggling when finding the error in the code which prevents the data I input in the text box from being put into my database

Tags: c#, winforms

When I have entered all the details into my Registration form it comes up with my error message and does not store the data in my database. I have tried loads of different ways to store the data into my db however none seem to be working. ID is college ID which is used to store students information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace NEWNEABlackjack
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnRegistered_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new LOGIN();
            myForm.Show();
            Close();

            string connection = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\m2101305\OneDrive - Middlesbrough College\NEW NEA\NEWNEABlackjack\NEWNEABlackjack\DBLogins.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            try
            {
                string query = "Insert into Table(Id,Username,FirstName,Surname,Password,Email,DOB) Values('" + IDtxtBox.Text + "','" + UNtxtBox.Text + "','" + FNtxtBox.Text + "','" + SNtxtBox.Text + "','" + PasswordtxtBox.Text + "','" + EAtxtBox.Text + "','" + DOBtxtBox.Text + "',)";
                SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                    ada.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Is Saved.");
                ClearData();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR Whilst Saving Data.");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }           
        }
        private void ClearData()
        {
            IDtxtBox.Text = "";
            UNtxtBox.Text = "";
            FNtxtBox.Text = "";
            SNtxtBox.Text = "";
            PasswordtxtBox.Text = "";
            EAtxtBox.Text = "";
            DOBtxtBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

[image: this is what i have wrote on the db]

Comment: Always test an SQL Query inside SQL Server Management Studio.  The error messages are much better in SSMS.  You can find the error when connecting with c# in SSMS using the explorer un Management where the log file is located.

Comment: I dont have access to this with it being a college computer I can only use visual studio

Comment: You should use Parameters to specify the values to insert, don't concatenate strings. This also makes data format mistakes more evident and prevents many other problems -- Are you sure you have to specify an `Id`? What is the data type of the `Id` Column in your database? Is it an auto-incrementing Column?

Comment: @Jimi how would you recommend me setting out the parameters and ID is an int

Comment: Create a new SqlCommand, use [SqlCommand.Parameters.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters) (not `AddWithValue()` here) to specify named parameters and their associated value, then set `[SqlDataAdapter].InsertCommand = [Your SqlCommand]` -- You haven't said whether the `Id` Column is an Identity Column. Verify this information and add it to the question

Comment: @Jimi do i need to remove the current SqlDataAdapter line

Comment: No, use your `ada` object, so after you have created a new SqlCommand and set its Parameters, you have `ada.InsertCommand = [You SqlCommand]`. Note that you're using `ada.SelectCommand` now -- You can find thousands of questions here about this matter. Search a bit further, you're missing critical pieces e.g., the use of `[SqlDataAdapter].Update()` -- You still haven't specified the data Type of the `Id` Column

Comment: @Jimi do you mean something like this:  ada.InsertCommand = SqlCommand.Parameters.Add();

Comment: Nope, of course not. You really need to invest more time reading the MSDN documentation and sample code you can find here (or anywhere else) -- See also [Generating commands with CommandBuilders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/generate-commands-with-commandbuilders)